# How to store return value of function in variable?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and have this function:

```
var numberOfItems = function() {
  $('.item_fields input[type="hidden"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'false';
  }).length; 
}
```

When I call it with `alert(numberOfItems);` rather than outputting an integer it outputs the function *code* itself:

```
function() {
  $('.item_fields input[type="hidden"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'false';
  }).length; 
}
```

I guess I must be missing something really fundamental here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: you don't need wrap it in __function__, you need just `var numberOfItems = $('.item_fields input[type="hidden"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'false';
  }).length; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your function doesn't return anything unless you put `return` at the beginning of the last (in this case only) statement.
2. You need to *call* the function to get its return value. `numberOfItems` is just "mentioning" the function; its value is the function object. `numberOfItems()` is calling the function. `()` is the operator that calls a function with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Return a value from the function:

```
var numberOfItems = function() {
  return $('.item_fields input[type="hidden"]').filter(function() {
    return $.trim($(this).val()) == 'false';
  }).length; 
};
```

Then call the function like this:

```
 alert( numberOfItems() );
```